# How to disable first checkbox after other one clicked in repeater

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have a repeater and there is a checkbox. When I click first one in checkedchanged event row information appear down below. But after first click I have a trouble. Sometimes informations are same. Because foreach always see the first click. For instance, I checked second one and I saw the informations. Then I click second one ok again I saw the informations, but this time I clicked again first one. Foreach can take first checkbox and the last one still checked before postback it's again doing second one's operation.
Is there any way to fix this?
Here is my sample code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInformations" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="ckChoose" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ckChoose_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
         <div id="foo" runat="server"> ... some basic titles ...</div>
     </ItemTemplate>
<asp:Repeater>
<div id="info" runat="server"> ... informations in here (textboxes, labels ..etc)</div>

CodeBehind:
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptInformations.Items)
{
       //CheckBox ckChoose= (CheckBox)sender;
       CheckBox ckChoose= item.FindControl("ckChoose") as CheckBox;
       if (cBoxChoose.Checked)
       {
            ... database process ...
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for what I understand you are trying to trigger an event everytime you check the checkbox and it will show certain info according to the row of the repeater it belongs to, for this I have made this example on a page called Repeater.aspx, using an event that will only fire for one checkbox and not for all:

*Repeater.aspx:*

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="ckChoose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ckChoose_CheckedChanged"/>
         <div id="foo" runat="server"> <%# Eval("Field2")%></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
<div id="info" runat="server"> ... informations in here (textboxes, labels ..etc)</div>
```

*Repeater.aspx.cs (Codebehind):*

```
partial class Repeater1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private System.Collections.Generic.List<Item> Elements()
    {

        Generic.List<Item> itemList = new Generic.List<Item>();
        itemList.Add(new Item("1", "One"));
        itemList.Add(new Item("2", "Two"));

        return itemList;

    }


    protected void  Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            this.repeater.DataSource = this.Elements();
            this.repeater.DataBind();

        }

    }


    protected void ckChoose_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        this.info.InnerHtml = "checkbox:" + chk.ID + " foo:" + ((HtmlGenericControl)chk.Parent.FindControl("foo")).InnerText;

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I fix it with namingcontainer. It works perfect.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cBoxx = item.FindControl("ckChoose") as CheckBox;
            current_cbId = cBoxx.NamingContainer.UniqueID.ToString();

            if (cBoxx.Checked)
            {
                ... some operations ...

            }

            if (cBoxChoose.NamingContainer.UniqueID.ToString() != current_cbId)
                cBoxChoose.Checked = false;
        }
```

Comment: Which event are you placing the foreach in?

Comment: Checkbox OnCheckedChanged event. But i'm really not sure, it works great but i have doubt about it. I'm not sure. Is it healty or best way?

Comment: If your goal is to trigger an action on selecting a chkbox based on the value of a certain item/row in the repeater, then my way is the best and you should try it because it goes directly towards one item only and it leaves the rest of checkboxes in their original state, your iteration and verifying are more resource consuming. Btw on your code i am getting  UniqueID.ToString() equal to current_cbId always so it never enters the if, is it correct?.